# Dart how to remove elements from the list untill the last element of the list

Tags: dart

How to remove elements from a list untill the last element of the list
for example:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

with

```
list.removeRange(1, ??)
```

wóuld evolve in

```
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 5):

[`List.length`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/length.html) is not just a getter; it's also a *setter*, and it can be used to truncate a `List` (or to grow one with nullable elements):

```dart
void main() {
  var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  list.length = 2;
  print(list); // Prints: [a, b]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/removeRange.html) you can see:

> A range from start to end is valid if 0 ≤ start ≤ end ≤ length.

So you can use the list's [length property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/length.html):

On your example:

```
final list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
list.removeRange(2, list.length);
print(list); // prints [a, b]
```

You can test it through DartPad [here](https://dartpad.dev/?).